# Connect chrome extension to an application

Tags: google-chrome-extension, windows

I want to send a message from chrome extension to a windows application. first i decided to use socket but i realized that we can use socket just in chrome app . is there any way to send this message to achieve my goal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The are 2 principal ways to do it.

1. You could expose a web server instead of raw sockets, something like a REST API. This is available to extensions.

   Even better, you could use the [WebSocket technology](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets) to approximate raw sockets - but you'll need to do all the handshaking first.
2. There's a specific API for what you're trying to do, called [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging). It's somewhat rigid in what it can do (it cannot connect to an existing process, for instance), but it's worth a look.